# How to get selected diagnostic in my VS Code Extension?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

With the help of the VS Code Extension API, I can get all current diagnostics in the open editors like this:

```
const allDiagnostics = vscode.languages.getDiagnostics();
```

I have written a command that deletes all mentions that generate these diagnostics: when you hover on the diagnostic, and click "Quick Fix...", the command appears, and after clicking it, all those mentions that produce the diagnostics are deleted from the editor:

[image: command]

However, I have not been able to find a way to get the selected diagnostic. For example, in the picture above, I would like the command to delete only `Calibrate()`, and not the other mentions that produce diagnostics in the editor. Something like:

```
const selectedDiagnostic = vscode.languages.getSelectedDiagnostic();
```

Is there a way to retrieve in my code only the selected diagnostic?

Answer (score 0):

In the [CodeActionProvider](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CodeActionProvider%3CT%3E) in the method `provideCodeActions` the diagnostic is in the `context` parameter